# Using App script, want to Create bulk Sheets with Month Names and to insert sub sheets with week names in each month sheet ,but showing error

Tags: javascript

Using App script, want to Create bulk Sheets with Month Names and to insert sub sheets with week names in each month sheet, but showing the following error:

> Exception: Invalid argument: options. Should be of type: Map (line 16, file "TEST_4")

How to use Map function in this scenario, can any body pls give an idea.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1USiJJ-i4U0AY2uGT8tv4ScpFLupj1YcH4ZjDOV15eoc").getSheetByName("formule");
    var ssDates = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1ZKKVrJSrvKsyghkmZFs_ANSVq_6KrmTRxinwxQ3de2I").getSheetByName("DATES");

    var weeksInMonth = ssDates.getRange(8, 22, 172, 1).getValues().flat();
    var getWeeksheetNames = ssDates.getRange(8, 16, 744, 1).getValues();
    var monthNames = ssDates.getRange(8, 18, 172, 1).getValues();
    var create = []
    //MainLoop to create SpreadSheet with Month Names
    for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        create[i] = SpreadsheetApp.create(monthNames[i]);

        //SubLoop to insert Sheets with week Names and past dates & Formulaue
        for (let k = 0; k < weeksInMonth[i]; k++) {
            create[i].insertSheet(getWeeksheetNames[k]);//Line 16

        }

    }
}
```

**Editor screenshot**
[image: editor screenshot]

Comment: Could you add the code as text? This makes it easier to help you.

Comment: What is the expected behaviour? Do you want to create multiple sheets? There doesn't seem to be a method that accepts an array of values: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertsheet

Comment: Yes. I want to create crate multiple sheets with Week Names. If Array Values not allowed pls suggest how to add bulk Multiple Sheets.

Comment: Ok now got it            create[i].insertSheet(getWeeksheetNames[k].join()). Thank you MaartenDev